# How to read text files with Elm and Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, loader, elm, ports

I have written a simple quizz application with Elm. As it was explained in the tutorial, the only way in Elm to access external files is to use ports with Javascript. So I have included ports in my Elm file, and I now have to add them in the `index.js` file that I use as an entry point. I use webpack to build the complete app.
However, I don't get the webpack logic. This is my file tree:

```
resources
    |---- images
    |---- questions
              |---- question_1.txt
              |---- question_2.txt
              |---- ...
    |---- scores
              |---- scores_table.json
src
    |---- MyElm.elm
    |---- Questions.elm
    |---- index.js
    |---- index.html

webpack.config.js
```

My JS component needs to read all possible questions in the `questions` folder to both determine the total number of questions and provide them to Elm through ports.
In the same way, the JS component needs to parse the `scores_table.json` file to send results to the Elm app.

What can I use in my `index.js` app to read these files? I tried with `require`, but I think I didn't use it correctly.

It's my first question on Stack Overflow, so if there's anything missing, please tell me.

**Minimal example**

This is a simplified version of what I have:

`webpack.config.js`

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: [
      './src/index.js'
    ]
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.txt$/,
        use: 'raw-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ]
      },
      {
        test:    /\.html$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader:  'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test:    /\.elm$/,
        exclude: [/elm-stuff/, /node_modules/],
        loader:  'elm-webpack-loader?verbose=true&warn=true',
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],

    noParse: /\.elm$/,
  },

  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    stats: { colors: true },
  },

};
```

`index.js`

```
const RESOURCES_DIR = "../resources/";
const IMAGES_DIR = RESOURCES_DIR + "images/"
const QUESTIONS_DIR = RESOURCES_DIR + "questions/"
const SCORES_DIR = RESOURCES_DIR + "scores/"

require("./index.html");
const scores_table =
    require(SCORES_DIR + "scores_table.json");

var total_question_nb = 0;
var questions_table = [];
var end = false;

while (!end) {
    try {
        data = require(
            "raw!" +
            QUESTIONS_DIR +
            "question_${total_question_nb}.txt");
        questions_table.push(data);
        total_question_nb += 1;
    } catch (e) {
        end = true;
    }
}

console.log(questions_table[0]);
console.log(total_question_nb);

var Elm = require("./MyElm.elm");
var mountNode = document.getElementById("elm-app");

var app = Elm.MyElm.embed(mountNode);

// Need to add port gestion there
```

`MyElm.elm`

```
...
import Questions
...
```

`Questions.elm`

```
...
-- (current_question_no, ans_id)
port ask_question_score : (Int, Int) -> Cmd msg

-- next_question_no
port ask_next_question : Int -> Cmd msg

-- question_score
port receive_question_score : (List Int -> msg) -> Sub msg

-- (next_question_no, total_question_nb, next_question_text)
port receive_next_question : ((Int, Int, String) -> msg) -> Sub msg

-- ()
port receive_end_question : (() -> msg) -> Sub msg
...
```

And this is what I get when I load the page using Webpack:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../resources/scores/scores_table.json".
    at r (app.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
    at r (app.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
    at r (app.js:1)
    at app.js:1
    at app.js:1
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @PirateX I added what a simplified version of what I have, but it's hard to really produce a Minimal example, as I don't know how to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR** You'll need to setup Webpack's [code splitting with dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) to enable dynamic `require`'s

Webpack is designed to compress all of your source files into one 'build' file. This, of course, relies on identifying which files you're importing. When you pass an expression rather than a plain string to `require`, webpack may not correctly identify the files you want.

In order to explicitly tell webpack what to include, you can use a "dynamic" import, ie [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports). I'd say code splitting is rather advanced, if you want to avoid it, just hardcode the files you want to import. That should be fine if the files don't change often.

---

### Examples

If you know the filenames:

```
const scores = require('../resources/scores/scores_table.json')
// or
import scores from '../resources/scores/scores_table.json'

// The `import()` function could be used here, but it returns a Promise
// I believe `require()` is blocking, which is easier to deal with here
// (though not something I'd want in a production application!)
const questions = [
  require('../resources/questions/question_1.txt'),
  require('../resources/questions/question_2.txt'),
]
```

If you want to dynamically import files (like you would probably do with questions):

```
// Utility function
// Example:
//     arrayOfLength(4) -> [0, 1, 2, 3]
const arrayOfLength = length =>
  (new Array(length)).fill(0).map((val, i) => i)

const questionsCount = 100 // <- You need to know this beforehand

// This would import questions "question_0.txt" through "question_99.txt"
const questionPromises = arrayOfLength(questionsCount)
  .map(i =>
    import(`../resources/questions/question_${i}.txt`)
      .catch(error => {
        // This allows other questions to load if one fails
        console.error('Failed to load question ' + i, error)
        return null
      })
  )

Promise.all(questionPromises)
  .then(questions => { ... })
```

With the dynamic imports, you need to handle promises. You could also use `async` / `await` to make it look a bit nicer (that isn't support in all browsers -- needs transpiling set up)

---

If the files *do* change often, that means you are frequently modifying questions and/or the score table, and you should probably be using a database instead of dynamic imports.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll give a look at the link you provided. One more question, now I know how to pack my files with Webpack, but how to read them inside the `index.js` file? Is the method I use correct (require with loader prefix) ?

Comment: You shouldn't need the loader prefix, because you added the raw loader in the webpack config. I added some examples for dynamic imports. Disclaimer: I haven't tested these!

Comment: Looking at that example, I'm starting to think you should really be using a database... or, just stick all the "questions" and "score_table" into a JSON file, import that, and call it a day.

Comment: My solution will allow to change files without rebuilding with webpack.

Comment: Ah, yes, @rofrol is correct, not sure why I didn't think of that. You can serve the config file(s) along side your built JS, which allows your JS to fetch the config file from the server.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. The only point I don't get is "is there any distinction with the code to tell webpack to pack a file and the code to read a file?". Actually, I only have a few questions for the quizz (102), and they are not going to change often. However, I would like to avoid hardcoding each filename. But putting all of the stuff in a JSON would be easy!

Comment: "*is there any distinction with the code to tell webpack to pack a file and the code to read a file?*" All of the 'imported' files are added, in some way, to the bundle / output. JavaScript is the only file type that Webpack can handle by itself though -- Webpack knows how to combine multiple JavaScript files into one. For any other type, you need a loader, which parses the file and decides how to add it to the bundle. Maybe it's output as a separate file, maybe it's somehow converted to JavaScript (CSS can be 'inlined' by outputing simple JavaScript which appends the CSS text to the document)

Comment: My bad, I don't know how but I didn't see your examples, maybe I'm a bit tired. Now I have a clear view of how to do it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This I use in React project. It will allow you to change files without rebuilding with webpack:

in `config/index.js`

```
const CONFIG_FILE = '/config.json';

let loadedConfig = {};

export const loadConfig = () => {
  const headers = new Headers();

  headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
  try {
    return fetch(CONFIG_FILE, { headers })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((json) => { loadedConfig = json; });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  }
};

export default () => ({ ...loadedConfig });
```

In `index.jsx` I load it:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { loadConfig } from 'config';

loadConfig().then(() => {
  require.ensure([], (require) => {
    const App = require('App').default;
    ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
      document.getElementById('root'),
    );
  });
});
```

And then I import it and use

```
import config from 'config';

console.log(config().SOME_VAR_FROM_JSON);
```